# Data Storing out Weird when Looping through Pandas DF in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am looking to loop through each row in my pandas dataframe in order to pull out the distinct play_id and the associated game_id. (Example in picture)

When I run the print function in Python I see the desired data. However when I store the data out ex. id_game=(ids) I get a very different format for the value.

Any thoughts on why or how to get the actual values I see in the print to be stored? Sorry if I am missing something basic it here. But I need the distinct play_id's to be stored so I can loop through them via another api call.

Thanks,

Code:

```
for ids in data.id:
for row in data.quarters: 
    for entry in row: 
        for play_ids in entry['pbp']:
            print(ids)
            print(play_ids['id'])
            id_game=(ids)
            id_plays=(play_ids['id'])
```

[Photo of Print and Stored Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttmvp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. Works fine and stored as an array instead for future iterations. Will work for now not sure on processing/best practices.

```
import numpy as np 
tdlist = []

for ids in data.id:
for row in data.quarters: 
    for entry in row: 
        for play_ids in entry['pbp']:
            id_game=(ids)
            play_id=(play_ids['id'])
            tdlist.append([id_game,play_id])

arraylst = np.array(tdlist)
```